# Batch file copy with date and time

Tags: windows-7-x64

I'm trying to figure this out need some help. I need to make a program that copy's my Log file  and rename with date and time to different directory. Prior to loading the program not sure how to do it if any help would be great.

Comment: So, what have you tried, and what are the problems?

Comment: Why punish a brand new user asking his first question? Let's not get happy on the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file that will copy all log files to an archive folder appending the date to each:

```
@Echo Off
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
Set Day=%%A
Set Month=%%B
Set Year=%%C
Set All=%%C%%B%%A
)
@For %%a in ("*.log") do copy %%a "archive\%%~na_%All%.LOG"
```